# FCC Basic JavaScript: Testing Objects for Properties

Tags: javascript

guys I am stuck at this for a while now and can't make it work what should I do.
the problem is attached to this IMG URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDM0M.png

Comment: The problem shouldnt be in the url. You need to provide [mcve] in your post

Comment: it's just an image. How else should I ask this?

Comment: you should copy paste your code here and also the question would be optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bracket pair `[]` instead of dot `.` notation. `return obj[checkProp]`